# How to generate class files form src java files in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying build the android project from command line.I want to convert the .java file in **src** folder to class files.I want to generate the class files in any other location in **/classes** folder.Please tell me how to do this ?

I amusing the follwing command but i get error as package R does not exist

```
D:\androidtest\src\com\example\project>javac -d D:\androidtest\bin\cla
sses -classpath C:\Users\admin\android-sdks\platforms\android-19\android.jar;D:\
androidtest\gen\com\example\project\R.java *.java
```

Answer (score 0):

give the following command while compiling your program

javac -d C:\folder_path\classes

For more details refer java documentation at following link
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: Please check my update answer what to change in my command @gujralam

Comment: what error are you getting and why you have specified *.javacls at the end

Comment: sorry that mistake while typing.Please tell now @gujralam

Comment: To me your syntax looks correct. Did you try executing this command. Is it working or giving errors. please report any errors on the forum

Comment: I guess can i set jar & java files into classpath at same time .becuase i am getting packge R does not exist. @gujralam

Comment: R.JAVA is automatically generated by android build system. You should compile your code base using Gradle for any android applicaiton

Comment: No i don't want to use gradle system.It's my compultion to use command line.@gujralam